# How to avoid No bean named 'something' is defined exception?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to avoid the `No bean named 'something' is defined` exception when the related resource is not available.

I have a project, which is divided into three modules one of which is used by the other two modules. As per the requirements the shared module actually refers to one of the other two module's bean. Unfortunately, while executing the other module I am getting the `No bean named 'something' is defined` exception since there is no bean name defined in that module.

> I would like to have `null` placed in that instead of raising an
>   exception and abnormally terminating the program. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which technology/frameowrk?

Comment: In the spring framework

Comment: Can you show us exception stack ?

Comment: Possible duplicat - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605657/no-bean-named-userdao-is-defined

Comment: @laune How to catch that exception? That is all what I wanted!

Comment: @JavaLearner No, that question is not what I wanted. My question is general, how to put `null` to be injected rather than throwing the exception and terminating the program?

Comment: How do you configure injection - using `@Autowired`, or in xml?

Comment: @axtavt `@Resource` annotation

Comment: The first thing I would do is check in my xml if I have defined the bean with that name. And yes, it is case sensitive.

Comment: @GPRathour Thanks for the reply. But it is not actually about whether or not to have the bean defined, but it is all about skipping the exception and putting null if the resource isn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For optional dependencies you can use `@Autowired(required = false)` instead of `@Resource`.

If you need to specify bean name explicitly (like in `@Resource`), use `@Qualifier` in addition to `@Autowired`:

```
@Autowired(required = false) @Qualifier("something") 
Foo something;
```

Comment: So that will not raise an exception if the bean isn't found?

Comment: Yes, `required=false` indicates that dependency is optional.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that and see. +1